# Scrapy + Django in production

Tags: python, json, django, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm writing a Django web app that makes use of Scrapy and locally all works great, but I wonder how to set up a production environment where my spiders are launched periodically and automatically (I mean that once a spiders complete its job it gets relaunched after a certain time... for example after 24h).
Currently I launch my spiders using a custom Django command, which has the main goal of allowing the use of Django's ORM to store scraped items, so I run:

```
python manage.py scrapy crawl myspider
```

and results are stored in my Postgres database.
I installed [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), since it seems that is the preferred way to run scrapy in production
but unfortunately I can't use it without writing a monkey patch (which I would like to avoid), since it use JSON for its web-service API and I get "modelX is not json serializable" exception.
I looked at [django-dynamic-scraper](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper), but it seems not be designed to be flexible and customizable as Scrapy is and in fact in docs they say:

> Since it simplifies things DDS is not usable for all kinds of
>   scrapers, but it is well suited for the relatively common case of
>   regularly scraping a website with a list of updated items

I also thought to use crontab to schedule my spiders... but at what interval should I run my spiders? and if my EC2 instance (I'm gonna use amazon webservices to host my code) needs a reboot I have to re-run all my spiders manually... mmmh... things get complicated...
So... what could be an effective setup for a production environment? How do you handle it? What's your advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question which led me to yours here. Here is what I think and what I did with my project.

> Currently I launch my spiders using a custom Django command, which has
>   the main goal of allowing the use of Django's ORM to store scraped
>   items

This sounds very interesting. I also wanted to use Django's ORM inside Scrapy spiders, so I did import django and set it up before scraping took place. I guess that is unnecessary if you call scrapy from already instantiated Django context.

> I installed scrapyd, since it seems that is the preferred way to run
>   scrapy in production but unfortunately I can't use it without writing
>   a monkey patch (which I would like to avoid)

I had idea of using subprocess.Popen, with stdout and stderr redirected to PIPE. Then take both stdout and stderr results and process them. I didn't have need to gather items from output, since spiders are already writing results to database via pipelines. It gets recursive if you call scrapy process from Django this way, and scrapy process sets up Django context so it can use ORM.

Then I tried scrapyd and yes, you have to fire up HTTP requests to the scrapyd to enqueue job, but it doesn't signal you when job is finished or if it is pending. That part you have to check and I guess that is a place for monkey patch.

> I also thought to use crontab to schedule my spiders... but at what
>   interval should I run my spiders? and if my EC2 instance (I'm gonna
>   use amazon webservices to host my code) needs a reboot I have to
>   re-run all my spiders manually... mmmh... things get complicated...
>   So... what could be an effective setup for a production environment?
>   How do you handle it? What's your advice?

I'm currently using cron for scheduling scraping. It's not something that users can change, even though they want but it has it's pros too. That way I'm sure users wont shrink the period and make multiple scrapers work at the same time.

I have concerns with introducing unnecessary links in chain. Scrapyd would be the middle link and it seems like its doing it's job for now, but it also can be weak link if it can't hold the production load.

Having in mind that you posted this while ago, I'd be grateful to hear what was your solution regarding the whole Django-Scrapy-Scrapyd integration.

Cheers